# how to interpret the "char term", can I omit single quote in literal

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I read the documentation "Oracle Database SQL Reference", in "Text Literal" section, it mentions that:

> Text, character, and string literals are always surrounded by single
>   quotation marks. If the syntax uses the term char, you can specify either a text literal
>   or another expression that resolves to character data — for example, the last_name
>   column of the hr.employees table. **When char appears in the syntax, the single
>   quotation marks are not used**.

should I interpret that the bolded part instructs I can omit single quote in string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in that statement, "the syntax" is not referring to the diagram given in the diagram given out underneath the statement, it refers to other syntax illustrated in the book. In those others, there are 'char' specified in them.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the picture underneath mentioned description:
[image]

In this picture there are characters: N n and Q q that **appear in the syntax**.
And for these characters we are not using qotation marks.
For example:

```
SELECT n'ala ma kota' FROM dual;
```